# Javascript: how to prevent keypress used to dismiss alert from triggering key event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, alert, keyevent

I am creating a web-based experiment using Javascript / JQuery which requires users to give responses by pressing certain keys, but not others. If they press the wrong key, they are supposed to get an alert popup telling them that they pressed the wrong keys. The experiment should stop waiting for the next keypress while the alert is displayed, but go back to waiting once the alert is dismissed.

The problem I'm having is that if the alert is dismissed by pressing the ENTER key, it seems to be registered by the key event handler, thus triggering another alert (because ENTER isn't one of the permitted keys), even though I thought I'd written it in such a way that the key event handler shouldn't be called until after the alert is dismissed. My question is, how to ensure that an ENTER keypress used to dismiss the alert will not be received by the subsequently called event handler?

Here's some code:

```
function waitForKeypress( permittedKeys, callbackFn ) {
    returnFn = function(e) {
        $(document).unbind('keyup',returnFn);
        if ( permittedKeys.indexOf( e.which )!=-1 ) {
            callbackFn( { "success": true, "value": e.which } );
        } else {
            callbackFn( { "success": false } );
        }
    }
    $(document).keyup( returnFn );
}

var callback = function(data) {
    if ( data.success ) {
        goDoOtherStuff();
    } else {
        alert( "error message" );
        waitForKeyPress( permittedKeys, callback );
    }
}

waitForKeyPress( permittedKeys, callback );
```

I should explain that the reason I THOUGHT that an ENTER keypress used to dismiss the alert would not be received by the event handler in waitForKeyPress is because (I thought) Javascript should halt execution as long as the alert is displayed, so that the waitForKeyPress call inside the callback function should not go off until the alert has been dismissed, which is to say, after the ENTER key has been released.

(My actual waitForKeyPress is more complicated than the above - it waits for PAIRS of key presses, with only certain pairs permitted, which is the reason why I needed to make it a separate function in the first place. I don't think the stuff I removed is related to my problem, though.)

EDIT: some people suggested this might have to do with the event handler not being unbound properly. I'm sure this isn't the issue. Here's a much more concise example, where the event handler isn't even bound at all until after the alert, but the same issue arises:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert( "Hello world" );
$(document).keyup( function() { alert( "Goodbye cruel world." ) } );
</script>
</html>
```

Pressing ENTER to dismiss Hello World will immediately call up Goodbye cruel world.

Comment: Change the alert to confirm and read the return.

Comment: call e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: @rlemon - Done - confirm returns "true" when I press ENTER - so ... now what?

Comment: @SteveH. - done, but this doesn't seem to change anything - why would it?

Comment: Unbind the event when you show the confirm. Rebind at the end of the confirm.

Comment: @rlemon - Doesn't my current code already do that? (At the beginning of returnFn, I unbind keyup, which should take effect before the confirm. It's not rebound until the next call of waitForKeyPress, which is after the confirm.)

Comment: I added a simpler example to illustrate that the issue doesn't have to do with anything that happened before the alert.

Comment: Your [last example](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/U4ZRH/) works fine for me in Chrome. What browser are you getting this in. This might help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hm. I cannot reproduce the issue in Firefox using your fiddle, but I still get the issue using my complete HTML file. I've added the entire HTML code to my original post in hopes of clarifying where the issue lies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unbind keyUp before showing the alert

**edit #1**

I tried the example code in your edit on Safari 6 OS X 10.7.

You're right.

This happens because standard buttons, like tke "Ok" of the alert dialog, that have the key equivalent "Return", are pressed (I mean the button) when a Return **keydown** occurr. In other words the dialog is dismissed as the user **press** return and doesn't wait for Return to be released.

So the user press "Return", the dialog is dismissed, keyup is binded, the user releases "Return", the event is fired.

You may work around this behaviour in different ways.

The easier one (if it fits your needs) is binding keydown instead of keyup

```
alert( "Hello world" );
$(document).keydown( function() { alert( "Goodbye cruel world." ) } );
```

Otherwise you may check what key is pressed and ignore "Return".

Keep in mind that keydown is triggered also by pressing CMD (for example if the user wants to close the window with CMD-W), arrow keys (that normally allow user to scroll the window if content is bigger that the viewport), etc.

So either if you stck with keyup or switch to keydown some sort of filtering would be appropriate.

Hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't my current code already do that? (At the beginning of returnFn, I unbind keyup.)

Comment: I added a simpler example to illustrate that the issue doesn't have to do with anything that happened before the alert.

Comment: Thanks! These solutions work. Any way to change the default behavior of alert so that it ends with keyup rather than keydown if ENTER is pressed?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible. Perhaps the "alert" is not a good way to interact with the user on modern web sites.

Comment: What would you recommend instead?

Comment: a javascript implemented modal dialog. eventually taking advantage of jquery. take a look at this, there are some samples http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/ajax-lightbox-modal-dialog-solutions/